# GROUPing two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

Could someone explain to me why you **have** to group two columns together here?
[Link](https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-aggregate-function-exercise-11.php) to page with code etc.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please could you [edit] your question to include the details as text, rather than an image?

Answer (score 1):

Because you want the highest of unique(customer, date).

If a customer orders twice on Monday and once on Tuesday you want the output to be their highest value order from Monday and their order from Tuesday.